# getting dead letter from Actor when trying to get back the response from it

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have ParentActor and 2 ChildActors  here is my code

```
Class ParentActor extends Actor {

val mongoActor = context.of.....
val esActor = context.of ............

def receive {
case InserInMongo(obj) =>
val mFuture = ask(mongoActor, InsertDataInMongo(object)).mapTo[Boolean]
      mFuture.onComplete {
        case Success(resultMongo) =>
             sender ! resultMongo
        case Failure(e) =>
            sender ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(e)
            throw e
        }   

case InserInES(obj) =>
val eFuture = ask(esActor, InsertDataInES(object)).mapTo[Boolean]
      eFuture.onComplete {
        case Success(resultES) =>
             sender ! resultES
        case Failure(e) =>
            sender ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(e)
            throw e
        }
}
}
```

here is the calling code

```
class Demo {
    val mongoFuture = ask(parentActor, InsertInMongo(obj))
            .mapTo[Boolean]
            .recover {
              case e =>
                println("error in mongo: " + e)
                false
            }

          val esFuture = ask(parentActor, InsertInES(obj))
            .mapTo[Boolean]
            .recover {
              case e =>
                println("error in ES: " + e)
                false
            }

          val f = Future.sequence(List(mongoFuture, esFuture))
          val result: Seq[Boolean] = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
          log.info ("result {}",result)
}
```

everything works fine but if i get some MongoException in mongoChildActor i am unable to get the parent actor result for ES

here is what i am getting

```
17:19:45.782 [MyActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef - Message [java.lang.Boolean] from Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/user/ParentActor#1383701267] to Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

All i want is if i got exception in mongo i got the exception and then it should proceed with ES and return its result (either its successful value or exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't throw exceptions in `receive`, and don't close over `sender` (`sender` is a function, that is only valid in the context of `receive`, you are using it inside `.onComplete`, on a different thread).

Something like this should do what you want:

```
 import akka.pattern.pipe
 def receive: Receive = {
   case InserInMongo(obj) =>
     ask(mongoActor, InsertDataInMongo(object)).pipeTo(sender)   

  case InserInES(obj) =>
     ask(esActor, InsertDataInES(object)).pipeTo(sender)

 }
```

Or, even easier:

```
 def receive: Receive {
   case msg: InsertDataInMongo =>
      mongoActor.forward(msg)
   case msg: InsertDataInES =>
      esActor.forward(msg)
 }
```